# Emacs macro to join lines?

Tags: emacs

I have several thousand lines of delimited data.  Unfortunately some of my data wrapped to a new line.  How can I search for all lines that do not contain my delimeter then join with the prior line, skip to the next line then continue until the end of the buffer?

### Buffer before

1243|This is all one
line
1235|This fits on one line.
43223|This line wraps
for some reason.

### Buffer after

1243|This is all one line
1235|This fits on one line.
43223|This line wraps for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good job for keyboard macros.  Try something like this:

```
C-x (
M-x isearch-forward-regexp RET
^[^|]*$ RET
M-^
C-x )

where
  C-x (                            begins recording a keyboard macro, which consists of
  M-x isearch-forward-regexp RET   searching forward using a regular expression
  ^[^|]*$                          representing a line containing no | characters, then
  M-^                              joining the current line to the previous line and
  C-x )                            ending the keyboard macro definition.
```

This macro can be invoked manually multiple times with C-x e (kmacro-end-and-call-macro), or you could save it as a function and call it programmatically as described at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacrosTricks.

Comment: Invoke it with `C-u 10000 C-x e` for maximum fun!

Comment: @Ivan Andrus: More specific from the EmacsWiki on [InfiniteArgument](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfiniteArgument): _To repeat a macro an infinite number of times use `C-u 0`. This will repeat the macro until the function quits (for example, by ending the reach of the buffer) or if the user cancels the command with a `keyboard-quit` of `C-g`._

Answer (score 4):

Try `M-x query-replace-regexp`, search for

```
^\(.\+|.\+\)\n\([^|]\+\)$
```

And the replacement:

```
\1\2
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-j") 'join-line)