# how to change ~/.emacs to auto split screen and run eshell

Tags: emacs

After loading emacs, I always run the following command to setup the work environment:

1> `C-x 2` to split the window as two buffers

2> `C-x o` to move cursor to the new created buffer

3> `M-x eshell` to enter shell mode

4> `C-x o` to move back to the original buffer.

**Question**> Is there a way that I can do all these automatically or at least make it little easier.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this in your .emacs file:

```
(split-window)
(other-window 1)
(shell)
(other-window 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can record this sequence as a keyboard macro, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1331005/552759).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using some other shell workflow with a popup window.

Here are two similar solutions:

- [EmacsWiki ShellPop](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShellPop)
- [and a bit shorter solution](http://tsdh.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/a-quick-pop-up-shell-for-emacs/)

HTH